# Submitting Form via AJAX Request

Tags: backbone.js

What is backbone's convention/best practice for retrieving data from a RESTful web service, based on data entered in a form?

From what I understand I can register a click observer in the **view**, so when the form submit button is clicked the **view** will retrieve the data from the form. But I'm unclear on whether I execute the AJAX call from the **view**, **model**, or **router**.

Essentially, I'm unclear as to which of the following is convention:

1. Have the **view** get the parameters, execute the AJAX call and then pass the returned JSON to the **model**
2. Have the **view** get the parameters and pass them to the **model** and have it execute the AJAX call and retrieve the data from the web service
3. Have the **view** get the parameters and pass them to a **router** and have it execute the AJAX call and populate the appropriate model and view accordingly?

**NOTE:** I need to submit search criteria to a RESTful Web Service, which expects the data to be POSTed; correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem like I can use: `fetch` or `save`. Should I create a function within the model that uses $.ajax({...}) to post the params and receive the JSON data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The backbone.js models are already setup to do RESTful requests. Method 2 is what you want to do.

The only thing you have to setup in the model is a URL:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://path/to/my/RESTful/service'
});

MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
       'submit #myform': 'saveToModel'
   },

   initialize: function() {
       // ...
   },

   saveToModel: function() {
       // this triggers a RESTFul POST (or PUT) request to the URL specified in the model
       this.model.save({
          'foo': 'Foo!',
          'bar': 'Bar!'
       });
   }


});
```

Comment: `fetch` and `save` don't seem to be viable options (see original post). Should I create a new function that handles the request?

Comment: Backbone is smart about RESTful services. `save()` works perfectly fine for this use case. The model knows that it should use a `POST` request when it is a new resource. That is, if there is no `id` element set on the model. If there is an `id` element set the model will use a `PUT` request. `fetch` on the other hand will use a `GET` request.

Comment: I am kinda of new to Backbone but shouldn't POST data be going to a controller/route that handles it? That's more according to the MVC principle in my honest opinion... But if you want to do a POST to a route, how does that work in Backbone? In sammy.js for example this is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Bind the submit event to the form id or the div id, not the button id.